# Counting the number of same elements in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Let, $\mathcal{E'}$ is the set of all sequences where:

1. Any element of $\mathcal{E'}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}=\mathbb{N}_1$.
2. In any element of $\mathcal{E'}$, every distinct number appears finitely many times.

Let, $\mathcal{E}$ is the set of all elements of $\mathcal{E'}$which are in non-decreasing order with entries from $\mathbb{N}_1$. ( We define a function $A:\mathcal{E'}\rightarrow \mathcal{E}$, where $A$ rearranges a element of $\mathcal{E'}$ in non-decreasing order.)

Now choose an element(say, $S$) from $\mathcal{E}$. Let, $\rho$ is an operation on $S$, such that $\rho(S)=(f(n))_{n=0}^{\infty}$, where $f:\mathbb{N}_1\rightarrow \mathbb{N}_1$, with $f(n)=$ the of number of times $n$ appeared in the sequence $S$.

Let $\mathcal{H}\subset \mathcal{E}$ is the set of all such $S\in \mathcal{E}$ for which $\rho(S)\in \mathcal{E'}$. Arranging elements of $\rho(S)$ in non-decreasing order, we will get an element of $\mathcal{E}$, which is $A(\rho(S))$. Essentially, if $A(\rho(S))\in \mathcal{H}$, we can get $\rho(A(\rho(S)))\in \mathcal{E'}$. Again, arranging elements of $\rho(A(\rho(S)))$ in non-decreasing order, we will get an element of $\mathcal{E}$, which is $A(\rho(A(\rho(S))))=(A\circ\rho)^2(S)$. We continue this process, and will get a set of sequences $((A\circ\rho)^m(S))_{m=0}^{\infty}\subset \mathcal{H}$ with $(A\circ\rho)^0(S)=\rho^0(S)=S$.

---

**Questions:**

1. Consider the set, $((A\circ\rho)^m(S))_{m=0}^{\infty}$. Let $N\in \mathbb{N}$. Can we find a $N$, for a given $S\in \mathcal{E}$ such that $(A\circ\rho)^N(S)=S$?
2. Can we find a $S\in \mathcal{E}$, for each $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(A\circ\rho)^N(S)=S$?

---

I made this question actually, so if you find any problem, please let me know. Also see the [MO post.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280838/counting-the-number-of-same-elements-in-a-sequence)

Comment: What you describe in property 1 is not "not ordered", but rather "up to rearrangement of *finitely many* terms"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I don't know the terms actually. That is why I explained it. Is that called "up to rearrangement of finitely many terms"?

Comment: If we only consider 1., sequences differeing by rearranging infinitely many terms will not be equivalent, but later you want the sorted sequence to be equivalent. I just want to emphasize that these are two different equivalence relations, one has to be careful. E.g., the sorted sequence of $2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9,\ldots$ is $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,\ldots$, but it takes infinitely many swap to get there ...

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280838/counting-the-number-of-same-elements-in-a-sequence without notification to either site.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I added links, I did not know it is mandatory to give that MO link too. Thanks.